# IEnumerable<T> to List<T>

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Ok I have looked all around and can't find an answer. I have a method that returns an

```
IEnumerable<ICar>
```

and the calling method is storing the results of the method in

```
List<ICar>
```

but I get the following error.

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Test.Interfaces.ICar> to 
System.Collections.Generic.List<Test.Interfaces.ICar>. An explicit conversion exists   
(are you missing a cast?)
```

I looked on msdn at

```
IEnumerable<T> interface and List<T> class.
```

The following line is from msdn.

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection,   
IEnumerable
```

I just don't understand why I can't assign

```
IEnumerable<ICar> to List<ICar>.
```

Can someone please explain this to me. What am I missing.

Comment: Have you tried calling ToList() on the returned object?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#". That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 10):

Not all `IEnumerable<T>` are `List<T>`. The reverse is true.

You can either try to cast to `List<T>` which is bad practice and could fail if it really is not a list or you can create a new list from the enumeration

```
new List<T>(yourEnumerable);
```

or using Linq

```
yourEnumerable.ToList();
```

Comment: Uhh, don't cast to `List<T>`, it could cause problems in the future. Just use one of the two methods above.

Comment: Yes.. hence I stated that it could fail. Better practice to create a new list from the enmeration if you really want a List<T>

Comment: @aqwert I did try new List<T>(yourEnumerable); and that worked I just wanted to understand why I couldn't go from an     IEnumerable<T> to List<T> it just seems like that would be ok to do.

Comment: You can through a cast. however there are many classes such as ObservableCollection<T> that also implements IEnumerable<T> so casting is not a good thing to do. The compiler does not know which one you want so you to be explicit to make sure you know what you want and not making any silly errors. You can go from List<T> to IEnumerable<T> because it knows that works with no ambiguity.

Comment: @aqwert This line says it all to me **Not all IEnumerable<T> are List<T>. The reverse is true**. And that is why I have to create a new list from the enumeration. Thanks to everyone for all help.

Answer (score 3):

`List<ICar>` implements `IEnumerable<ICar>` - you're correct. But that means that you can implicitly convert a `List<ICar>` to an `IEnumerable<ICar>` - *not* the other way around. To get around your problem, just call `ToList()` on the `IEnumerable` to convert it to a `List`.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `ToList` to convert your `IEnumerable<Car>` to a `List<Car>`.

```
IEnumerable<ICar> cars = ...;
List<ICar> list = cars.ToList(); // OK
```

This doesn't happen automatically because although you can try to downcast `IEnumerable<Car>`  to `List<Car>`:

```
IEnumerable<ICar> cars = ...;
List<ICar> list = (List<ICar>)cars; // Compiles, but could fail at runtime.
```

there is no [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) conversion operator, so the C# compiler disallows the assignment without a cast. The downcast could fail at runtime, so it is better to use `ToList` in most situations.

Answer (score 1):

An `IEnumerable<T>` CAN BE a `List<T>` but is not necessarily one. You can use LINQ's `IEnumerable<T>.ToList<T>()` to convert any `IEnumerable<T>` to `List<T>`

```
IEnumerable<T> foo = ThatMethodYouWereTalkingAbout();
List<T> bar;
if (foo is List<T>)
    bar = (List<T>)foo;
} else {
    bar = new List<T>(foo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All lists are IEnumerable, but all Innumerable are not lists. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) IEnumerable

> Exposes the enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a non-generic collection.

All IEnumerable promises   you is that you can get the next element. The List promises a lot more: e.g. access by index and that it as a finite length.

This is not the case with IEnumerable. For example the below  code doesn't actually create a list , indeed, you can't make a list from it. Every time you ask for a new element, it gives you one. But it only calculates it when asked. :

```
IEnumerable<int> Numbers() {
    int i=0;
    while(true) {
        yield return unchecked(i++);
    }
}
```

You want to call [ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) to get a list. Note this might note terminate in a case like the one above.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot assign a less derived type to a more derived type through variable assignment.  Thats not type safe.

In language spec. speak, `List<ICar>` is not assignment compatible with `IEnumerable<ICar>`.  But, the inverse is true.  `IEnumerable<ICar>` is assignment compatible with `List<ICar>`.

It makes more sense if you visualize assignment compatability as a relation.  If x <= y is true, then x >= y is not true (unless y = x).  (Concretely, 2 < 3 = true so 2 > 3 is not true.)

In your case, we can assign the value of a List of cars to a variable of type `IEnumerable<ICar>`.

If we can represent the relationship as

`List<ICar>` <= `IEnumerable<ICar>` = true.

Then it follows that

`List<ICar>` >= `IEnumerable<ICar>` = false

It's false because the first relation we know to be true.