# Cannot convert type IEnumerable to List

Tags: c#

I have been using C# with Unity3d for a few years now, but am just starting with .NET programming. I get the error:

Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<URL>`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.List<URL>`'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Here is my code:

```
namespace TestBrowserHistory
{
    public class Test1
    {
        public Test1()
        {

        }
          static void Main()
    {
        InternetExplorer myClass = new InternetExplorer();
        List<URL> calledList = myClass.GetHistory();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
        Console.WriteLine(calledList[1]);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    }
}

public class InternetExplorer
{
    // List of URL objects
    public List<URL> URLs { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<URL> GetHistory()
    {
        // Initiate main object
        UrlHistoryWrapperClass urlhistory = new UrlHistoryWrapperClass();

        // Enumerate URLs in History
        UrlHistoryWrapperClass.STATURLEnumerator enumerator =
                                           urlhistory.GetEnumerator();

        // Iterate through the enumeration
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            // Obtain URL and Title
            string url = enumerator.Current.URL.Replace('\'', ' ');
            // In the title, eliminate single quotes to avoid confusion
            string title = string.IsNullOrEmpty(enumerator.Current.Title)
                      ? enumerator.Current.Title.Replace('\'', ' ') : "";

            // Create new entry
            URL U = new URL(url, title, "Internet Explorer");

            // Add entry to list
            URLs.Add(U);
        }

        // Optional
        enumerator.Reset();

        // Clear URL History
        urlhistory.ClearHistory();

        return URLs;
    }

}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi! Maybe you could be a little more specific : where are you getting this error?  We don't need the source of your whole project for such a compilation error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IEnumerable<T> to List<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406410/ienumerablet-to-listt)

Comment: And duplicated here, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961375/casting-ienumerablet-to-listt

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You get that error because `myClass.GetHistory();` returns `IEnumerable<URL>`, which is not same as `List<URL>` at compile time, although it is actually `List<URL>` at runtime. Change method signature to return `List<URL>`, cause you already do that

```
public List<URL> GetHistory()
```

Other workarounds would be to cast method call result to `List<URL>`

```
List<URL> calledList = (List<URL>)myClass.GetHistory();
```

Or construct new list from result

```
List<URL> calledList = new List<URL>(myClass.GetHistory());
```

If you do not need List functionality, you could define `calledList` as IEnumerable

```
var calledList = myClass.GetHistory();
```

Comment: Or you could call .ToList() on the enumerable.

Answer (score 3):

Your definition of the `GetHistory` methods returns an IEnumerable, and you are assigning it to an IList. Either change the definition , or the usage.

If you don't need to change the collection I would change the definition of GetHistory to IEnumerable.

Answer (score 3):

A List is IEnumerable, but the reverse is not true.

If you need list operations, you should change your method to return an IList<> instead of IEnumerable.  Alternately, you should assign the return value to an IEnumerable variable instead of a List.  This will limit you to (without further manipulation) the IEnumerable methods (you can do a foreach and use LINQ things like .First, but you can't reference by specific position, for example).  Which might be enough for what you ultimately need it for.

Comment: Your first sentence says it all.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the error

```
List<URL> calledList = myClass.GetHistory();
```

Since `GetHistory` method returns `IEnumerable<URL>`

```
public IEnumerable<URL> GetHistory()
```

EDIT:

**Solution**: just change the return value of `GetHistory()` method to `IList<T>`

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but I'd guess the reason is the redundant creation of a new list instead of the reuse of the existing one.

Comment: In `GetHistory`, there is `return URLs;` and the type of `URLs` is `List<URL>`. Theoretically, you could just cast it back to its actual run-time type instead of creating a whole new list.

Comment: Right, I've overlooked that, thanks for pointing to this, makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

To get things working you just need to change the return type of your GetHistory() method to `List<URL>`.

You can typecast a List to an IEnumerable, but not the other way around. The compiler is told that GetHistory returns IEnumerable, and even though it *is* a list, it doesn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

In alternative to what others have said, you could simply:

```
GetHistory();
List<URL> calledList = URLs;
```

Since `GetHistory` modifies the `URLs` as its side-effect anyway, there is little purpose of returning any result from it. In addition to that, you might consider whether `GetHistory` needs to be *explicitly* called at all - perhaps the equivalent code should be implicitly executed when the `URLs` getter is first called?

Also, why aren't you using `foreach`?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use tolist() provided by Linq lamda to convert from IEnumerable to List.

```
using System.Linq;

List<URL> calledList = myClass.GetHistory().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
yield return U;
```

end of while block and remove

```
 return URLs;
```

after that function is like this

```
public IEnumerable<URL> GetHistory()
{
    // Initiate main object
    UrlHistoryWrapperClass urlhistory = new UrlHistoryWrapperClass();

    // Enumerate URLs in History
    UrlHistoryWrapperClass.STATURLEnumerator enumerator =
                                       urlhistory.GetEnumerator();

    // Iterate through the enumeration
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        // Obtain URL and Title
        string url = enumerator.Current.URL.Replace('\'', ' ');
        // In the title, eliminate single quotes to avoid confusion
        string title = string.IsNullOrEmpty(enumerator.Current.Title)
                  ? enumerator.Current.Title.Replace('\'', ' ') : "";

        // Create new entry
        URL U = new URL(url, title, "Internet Explorer");

        // Add entry to list
        URLs.Add(U);
        yield return U;
    }

    // Optional
    enumerator.Reset();

    // Clear URL History
    urlhistory.ClearHistory();


}
```