# Error 107 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2

Error   107 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
enter code here
              public IEnumerable<TempProductCart> Get()
    {
        IEnumerable<TempProductCart> q = rep.Get();
        var a= q.Select(x => new
         {
             x.Product.Name,
             x.ProductID,
             x.User.Username,
             x.ProductQty
         }).ToList();

        return a;


    }
```

Comment: you need to use a constructor of `TempProductCart` to project instead of the `new {}` (which creates anonymous object). The `TempProductCart` however should not be entity type (it should be such as DTO class).

Comment: The opposite conversion error is in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206957/cannot-convert-type-ienumerable-to-list).